# iOS multiple provisioning profiles with organization

Tags: ios, profile, provisioning, organization

I am a member of an iOS developer team, and would like to also get an individual iOS developer account. I've looked all over and have not been able to figure out how to do this. Does anyone know how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an Apple ID associated with more than 1 developer teams (individual is a team of 1), however that account can only be an Agent for 1 of those teams.

It's sometimes easier to have a separate account per team you are a member of.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. Guess I need another email address. : /

Answer (score 1):

I tend to have separate accounts using different email addresses. One for work and one for myself.